# Find $f'(0)$ for $f(x)=(x^3-\tan^3(x))^{\frac 15}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\, f(x)=(x^3-\tan^3(x))^{\frac 15}$ find $f'(0)$

I chart the function and its derivative, and it looks that the only possible value for $f'(0)$(assuming it exists) is $-1$, however, you can't just derive the function and then calculate $f'(0)$. If we go with the definition of the derivative we end up with this messy limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x^3-\tan^3(x))^{\frac 15}}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I could came up with. The limit is equivalent with
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3-\tan^3x}{x^5}=\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x-\tan x)(x^2+\tan^2 x+x\tan x )}{x^5}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\tan x }{x^3}.\frac{x^2+\tan^2 x+x\tan x}{x^2}$$
Now $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2+\tan^2 x+x\tan x}{x^2}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{\tan^2 x}{x^2}+\frac{x\tan x}{x^2}=3$$
Applying L'Hopital to $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\tan x}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\tan^2(x)-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{-\tan^2x}{3x^2} = - \frac 13$$ So the limit is $-\frac 13 3 = -1$
Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: You need to take the 5th root also which gives the answer $-1$. Apart from this your answer is perfect and that is the way one should approach it. +1

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x^3-\tan^3(x))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x-\tan(x))(x^2+\tan^2 x+x\tan x))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x-\tan(x))(x^2+x^2+x^2))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x-\tan(x))(3x^2))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x-(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^5)))(3x^2))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{((-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^5))(3x^2))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(-\frac{x^3\times 3x^2}{3}+o(x^7))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(-x^5+o(x^7))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x(-1+o(x^2))^{\frac 15}}{x}\to -1$$
for a visual sense
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqlrfldzu2

Comment: I've been struggling to do it without resorting to taylor series, lol

Comment: I got it, but it must be a simpler solution. Taylor series were not required for the students who took the exam.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f'(0) &=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(h^3 - \tan^3 h)^{1/5}}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \left(\dfrac{h^3 - \tan^3 h}{h^5}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h^3 - \tan^3 h}{h^5}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{3h^2 - 3\tan^2 h\sec^2h}{5h^4}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{6h - 6\tan h\sec^4h-6\tan^3h\sec^2h}{20h^3}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{6 - 6\sec^6h -
 42\tan^2h\sec^4h - 12\tan^4h\sec^2h}{60h^2}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{-120\tan h\sec^6h - 216\tan^3h\sec^4h - 24\tan^5\sec^2x}{120h}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\lim_{h \to 0} -\dfrac{\tan h}{h} + \dfrac{216\tan^3h\sec^4h + 24\tan^5\sec^2x}{120h}\right)^{1/5} \\
&=& (-1)^{1/5} \\
&=& -1
\end{array}$$

Comment: I hate to say that,  but I already  knew  that applying L'Hopital 5 times will work. I still hope for a simpler solution. Something you could compute in 5 min without being concerned that you did a miscalculation. Anyway thank you very much for your hard work.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative expression is as follows:

$$-\dfrac{3\left(\sec^2\left(x\right)\tan^2\left(x\right)-x^2\right)}{5\left(x^3-\tan^3\left(x\right)\right)^\frac{4}{5}}$$

However, this is for $x\neq$0. Thus, using the definition:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x^3-\tan^3(x))^{\frac 15}}{x}=\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\frac{(x-\tan(x)(x^2+\tan^2 x+x\tan x)}{x^5})^{\frac 15}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} ((\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^3})(1+\frac{\tan^2x}{x^2}+\frac{\tan x}{x}))^{\frac 15}=-\frac{1}{3}\times3=-1
$$
Now you should be familiar with taking the limit of each term.

**Since you want something rather than Taylor expansion, your best bet to compute the limit of each term is to use [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).**

Comment: Who said the derivative has to be continuous?

Comment: It does exist: the derivative is $-1$.

Comment: @JohnButler Can you show how you conclude that the lateral limits are both -1? More or less this is the question I asked.

Comment: That form is for $x\ne0$. You can't assume continuity and then extend the form to $0$. You have to actually use the definition of limit.

Comment: @JohnButler I need a formal proof, charts are not enough. The problem was asked at an exam, and at most you could probably spent 6-10 mins on it. The subject was only real calculus (high school level)so no complex analysis was required. A simple calculus proof must exist.

Comment: @JohnButler Which part of "that form is only for $x\ne0$" do you not understand?

Comment: Finally. I retracted my downvote and upvoted. Your method of finding the limit is better than what I have drafted, like 100 times.

Comment: Also, the graph you attached is completely wrong, because $f$ is defined (and is real) for all $x$, and so is $f'$.

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks for your kind attention and helpful points.

Comment: Wait, your limit evaluation is wrong. You forgot about the $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with taking limit of $\dfrac1{x^4}$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @KennyLau you're right, it needs more work, but I guess this the core idea. Almost falling asleep. More than welcome to improve my answer :)

Comment: @KennyLau My low rank does not let me to comment on your solution, Nice messy work :) Upvoted.

Comment: It appears that you are indeed trying to compute the derivative as per definition, but your notation has issue. The notation $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ refers to limit of derivative and not the derivative itself. Better be direct and write $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dots$ and note that there is no need here to consider lateral limits.

Comment: @motoras Sure. I had the idea but did not have time to develop it into a rigorous way. I think you got the idea from my effort which I am glad and came up with a correct answer. Good finishing! ;)